# Can Android library project be a single project (not in a multi-project build)?

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

Android libarary project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Error

```
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.
```

If I create a root project, and make the android library a module, and move the buildscript to the root project,  it will work.

root project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Android lib project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

settings.gradle:

```
include 'my-aar-project'
```

Can Android library be an independent project without root project? In other words, can we build AAR project as single project (not multi-project build)?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a project without an "app" component added (although you will have nothing to run to test your library).

Did you mean `include ':my-aar-project'`? Cause that with the lib build.gradle + android plugin should allow you to at least build

Comment: My questions is: For android lib project,  now we have to make it a module project. Is it possible to build AAR as single project (not multi-project bulid)? Thanks.

Comment: As far as i know android studio always works with the "root"... you could always manually build the aar regardless of android studio (although i don't know why you would want this), or keep it a sole module inside the root project and still be able to produce the aar directly.